# Custom GridView Item

Tags: android, android-layout, gridview, android-linearlayout, android-gridview

How to create a custom GridView item like below ?

[image]

Layout written by me -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@drawable/round_corner_drawable">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/market_image"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
    android:src="@drawable/default_image"/>

    <TextView

        android:id="@+id/nameTV"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:text="Text 1"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/priceTV"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:text="Text 2"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

To make it square, I added these lines in the adapters getView() method -

```
GridView grid = (GridView)parent;
int size = grid.getColumnWidth();
view.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(size, size));
```

After running it on the device, i am getting below result.
The texts below imageview are cropped and not visible. Also i want the imageview to go above the layout as shown in the image above. Please help

[image]

Image which i am using  -

[image]

Comment: Use FrameLayout instead of LinearLayout

Comment: I tried using FrameLayout but i have to show two text below the imageview.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i am able to solve it.
I have written below layout to get the desired output

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/rootView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="210dp"
    android:layout_height="240dp"
    android:background="@drawable/round_corner_drawable"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp">

    <TextView

        android:id="@+id/nameTV"
        android:layout_above="@+id/priceTV"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:text="Latin American Republic"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/priceTV"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:text="65$"/>
</RelativeLayout>

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/market_image"
    android:layout_width="190dp"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:src="@drawable/default_marketplace"/>




</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to give weight=1 to image layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@drawable/round_corner_drawable">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/market_image"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
    android:src="@drawable/default_image"/>

    <TextView

        android:id="@+id/nameTV"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:text="Text 1"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/priceTV"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:text="Text 2"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

As per above xml.

Answer (score 0):

try using following layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<View
    android:id="@+id/anchor"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/market_image"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/nameTV"
    android:layout_below="@+id/anchor"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/nameTV"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_above="@+id/priceTV"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:text="Text 1" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/priceTV"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:text="Text 2" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

or use following layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:weightSum="100"
android:orientation="vertical">

<ImageView
android:id="@+id/market_image"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height=match_parent
android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
android:layout_weight="10"
android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"/>

<TextView

    android:id="@+id/nameTV"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
     android:layout_weight="45"
    android:text="Text 1"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/priceTV"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
     android:layout_weight="45"
    android:text="Text 2"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: have you tried second solution given by me? you can try putting  android:scaleType="centerInside" in image view. What is the height of your image?

Comment: I have tried the second solution too. Added the image in the question so you can check it. Also i am forcing gridview to draw only two columns and then making the gridview items square as explained in the question